# Caroufredsel slider - keep variable width image in center of scroller

Tags: jquery, carousel, caroufredsel

I have a series of variable width images.  I want to rotate them in a carousel and have chosen 'carouFredSel' as it seems to be the most configurable one I can find.  I want one of the images to be centered horizontally in the browser always.  So with the traditional carousel images would be left-aligned by default, but here I want them to align around the image in the middle of the view, with consistent (10px) gaps between the images.  Here's an example: http://coolcarousels.frebsite.nl/c/2/.  This is great for fixed width images, but my images are variable in width.  This variable width is the issue.

I've done a quick mock-up to highlight this.  The code is as follows:

HTML:

```
<div class="strip">
    <div id="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-image">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/400x200" alt="" />                
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-image">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/117x200" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-image">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/317x200" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-image">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/400x200" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-image">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/317x200" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-image">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/150x200" alt="" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.strip {
    height: 210px;
    background: #333;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.carousel-image {
    float:  left;
    width: 410px;
    height: 306px;
    text-align: center;
}
.carousel-image img {
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

JS:

```
$(function () {

    $('#carousel').carouFredSel({
        width: '100%',
        align: 'center',
        items: {
            visible: 3,
            start: -1
        },
        scroll: {
            items: 1,
            duration: 1000,
            timeoutDuration: 3000
        },
        prev: '#prev',
        next: '#next',
        pagination: {
            container: '#pager',
            deviation: 1
        }
    });

});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qqBus/

You'll see if you remove the '.carousel-image' width it has the desired effect in making the images sit next to each other without gaps, but it also stops the middle image from being centered.

I wondered if anyone could figure out a way to achieve the effect I'm looking for?  I'm open to an alternative plug-in if such a thing exists, but having looked long and hard I can't find one that works with variable width images!

Thanks folks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this link http://samanthaswade.com/editorial.html

This is the slider plugin http://jquery.lemmonjuice.com/plugins/slider-variable-widths.php without centered images

And here is the centered image solution [enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/bschwartz/DQuc2/)

```
$( function() {
// slider 1
    $( '#yourslider' ).lemmonSlider( {
        infinite: true
    });
});
```